# Class design plus object literals in Cocoa Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Let us say that application has a concept of cars in it. A car is an instance of Car. There are a small number of possible cars and most, but not all of the data about a car is known at design time. Each kind of car is a singleton; there is at most one of each kind of Car per app.*

Since they are singletons, and since they are named, that suggests some sugar. The most important piece of sugar is this: when I import "Car.h", into a file, I want the symbols "MAFerrari", "MAMercedes", and "MAMclauren" to start showing up in my autocomplete where ever code completion thinks I am trying to provide an instance of a Car*.

My next greedy desire is that I want to be able to send instance methods to my MAFerrari literal, e.g. [MAFerrari topSpeed] means "get the singleton instance of Car that corresponds to the Ferrari and send topSpeed to it", but I acknowledge the utter triviality of this. Even pragmatists should know what their Utopia looks like.

Finally, if possible, I want  clean way to declare the constant properties of the three cars as literal data at the top of my Car.m file.

Now, again, I don't actually expect all of that to be possible in Objective C. I just want to know how close we can get to that all that.

The closest idea I've had is to subclass Car for each type of car and provide a +sharedInstance method for each one. sharedInstance can implement the singleton pattern: if it's initialized, return it, otherwise initialize it, store it (where? it should be private to the Car class hierarchy), then return it. Each subclass can implement its own initializer which contains the defaults for that subclass.

Here's what I don't like about this:

1. I think I have to import all the header files whenever I work with these subclasses. This absolutely sucks. Is there another way?
2. I have to create .m/.h file pair for every one of these subclasses. That seems like a lot of boilerplate, since they have no unique behavior.
3. [[MAFerrari sharedInstance] topSpeed] isn't quite as good as [MAFerrari topSpeed], but I acknowledge that this is trivial.

Anyway, how would you do it?

*In reality, it's not cars, but in-app purchase assets, for the curious.

Comment: All three of your concerns are unfounded.  1. you *can* just import some header named Car.h, but Car.h would need to be a wrapper header, rather than a superclass declaration to avoid circular imports. 2. Whoever said you could only have 1 class per file?  Look at NSString.h.  3. It is not recommended that you use convenience methods like that.  The cocoa guidelines (in the MRC days) stated that convenience methods should be reserved for initializers that return autoreleases values.  As much as you hate verbosity, you've bought into a language that's all about it, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is just a global variable. You can create a global variable named whatever you want (say, MAFerrari) and stick whatever you want in it — whether the contents of the variables are instances of multiple singleton classes or multiple instances of the same class doesn't really matter from the point of view of having global names to refer to the objects.

Comment: That sounds promising. How would you initialize the globals?

Comment: You could have a class method that initializes them, which you would call whenever you need to. Or you could use the +load method of any class, which gets called when the class is loaded in the runtime (typically when you app launches).

Comment: Alright, I think this is indeed what I want. I can't figure out how to use Obj-C object literals in globals, but I can stuff them into +init for now.

Comment: @masonk: The only kind of literal you can use outside of a function/method context is an NSString. The others are all just method calls in disguise, so they need to go inside a method. So you'll have to actually assign the variables in some setup method.

Comment: @Taum you have to pay attention that the classes you use in `+load` are already loaded, [see this link](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-05-22-objective-c-class-loading-and-initialization.html)

Answer (score 1):

Easy-peasy.

Note that these aren't singletons; they're just long-lived instances of a class stored in global variables.

```
//  Bolt.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Bolt : NSObject

// Properties

- (instancetype)initWithLength:(NSUInteger)length
                      diameter:(NSUInteger)diam
                        thread:(NSUInteger)thread
                         grade:(NSUInteger)grade;

// etc.

@end

extern Bolt * twentyFiveByTwelveCoarseThreadGradeEightBolt;
extern Bolt * fiftyByTenFineThreadGradeFiveBolt;
```

---

```
//
//  Bolt.m

#import "Bolt.h"

Bolt * twentyFiveByTwelveCoarseThreadClassEightBolt;
Bolt * fiftyByTenFineThreadGradeFiveBolt;

// This will be run before main() but after classes are loaded
__attribute__((constructor))
static void initialize_global_Bolts(void) 
{
    twentyFiveByTwelveCoarseThreadClassEightBolt = [[Bolt alloc] initWithLength:25
                                                                       diameter:12
                                                                         thread:175
                                                                          grade:8];
    fiftyByTenFineThreadGradeFiveBolt = [[Bolt alloc] initWithLength:50
                                                            diameter:10
                                                              thread:1
                                                               grade:5];

}

@implementation Bolt

- (instancetype)initWithLength:(NSUInteger)length
                      diameter:(NSUInteger)diam
                        thread:(NSUInteger)thread
                         grade:(NSUInteger)grade
{
    // Do initialization
}

@end
```

Now you can do things like `[fiftyByTenFineThreadGradeFiveBolt maximumTorque];` wherever Bolt.h is imported.

You can't put dictionary or other literals at top level, because they resolve into method calls, which can't be used outside of other methods.

Comment: Note that `initialize` is only called when the class (or one of its subclasses) receives a message for the first time. You're going to need to poke this class in some way to get those globals filled in. One alternative would be to implement `load` instead; another would be to write a function with the constructor attribute.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, @PeterHosey, for some reason I was thinking that messaging the global would itself cause `+initialize` to be run, but that's obviously nonsense.